# Conditional data watchpoint doesn't work in ARM GDB

Tags: c, debugging, arm, gdb, cortex-m

My intent is to be able to catch when a global variable has some exact value. GDB has [data watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) according to which this can be implemented.

Consider this simple program written for x86 Linux:

```c
int myVar = 0;

void debug_watchpoints() {
    for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++) {
        myVar++;
    }
}

int main() {
    debug_watchpoints();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the program with

```
gcc -o main -ggdb3 -Og main.c
```

And starting debugging with GDB:

```
max@PC-LT-23:~/stackoverflow$ gdb ./main
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.3-0ubuntu1) 8.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./main...
(gdb) b main 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1146: file main.c, line 9.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x1146: file main.c, line 9.
Starting program: /home/max/stackoverflow/main 

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:9
9   int main() {
(gdb) watch myVar if myVar==1337
Hardware watchpoint 3: myVar
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 3: myVar

Old value = 1336
New value = 1337
debug_watchpoints () at main.c:4
4       for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++) {
(gdb)
```

As you can see it halted the program at *exactly* the point in time when the variable was set to 1337.

Consider the **exact same program**, compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` for a STM32L476RG microcontroller which has a Cortex-M4F core. The used IDE here is System Workbench for STM32 (aka Eclipse) with a project generated by STM32CubeMX.

Now launching `openocd` gives

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00021-g524e8c8 (2019-04-12-08:33)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
padded zone erase set to 1
adapter speed: 8000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 8000 kHz
Info : STLINK v2.1 JTAG v34 API v2 M25 VID 0x0483 PID 0x374B
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 0.011074
Error: target voltage may be too low for reliable debugging
Info : Unable to match requested speed 8000 kHz, using 4000 kHz
Info : Stlink adapter speed set to 4000 kHz
Info : STM32L476RGTx.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08001340 msp: 0x20018000
```

A breakpoint is set in the `main` function and then the watchpoint is setup exactly like before. Also, a breakpoint is is set after the execution of the `debug_watchpoints()` function.

```
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 8.3.0.20190709-git
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) Reset_Handler () at ../startup/startup_stm32l476xx.s:63
63        ldr   sp, =_estack    /* Set stack pointer */

Temporary breakpoint 3, main () at ../Src/main.c:65
65      {

(gdb) watch myVar if myVar==1337
Hardware watchpoint 4: myVar
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x08000f46 in main at ../Src/main.c:70
4       hw watchpoint  keep y              myVar
        stop only if myVar==1337
(gdb)
```

When continuing the program, it now stops *at every modification of the variable* with a `SIGTRAP`, regardless of whether the condition was met or not.

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x08000ec2 in debug_watchpoints () at ../Src/main.c:54
54              for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++) {
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x08000ec2 in debug_watchpoints () at ../Src/main.c:54
54              for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++) {
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x08000ec2 in debug_watchpoints () at ../Src/main.c:54
54              for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++) {
(gdb) info breakpoint
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x08000f46 in main at ../Src/main.c:70
4       hw watchpoint  keep y              myVar
        stop only if myVar==1337
(gdb) print myVar
$2 = 3
```

I can continue for as many times as I want, it just breaks each and every time the variable is changed.

In my scenario of "debugging a memory corruption on the stack", I really need GDB to evaluate the condition correctly, otherwise the program stops a thousand times or more (every time a variable which happens to be at this memory location is changed) and not at only the specific time a specific value is written into it to catch a bug.

Why does `arm-none-eabi-gdb` differ here in its behavior from normal `gdb`? Could the error lie in the Cortex-M4 hardware debugging capabilities, `arm-none-eabi-gdb`, or `openocd` as the GDB server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, there's no working implementation in openocd, the debugger bridge you are using.

You can set by sw. Here a small snippet. COMP2, FUNCTION2, COMP1 and FUNCTION1 are DWT registers. Please note that you need to use two comparators linked together. Not all Cortex-m implementations support these features and not all comparators are linkable, it depends on your silicon. Also it seems that the capture is asynchonous. Generally my PC stops a few istruction after the trigger.

```
DWT->COMP2 = <address to compare>;
DWT->FUNCTION2 = 0;
DWT->COMP1 = <word to compare>;
DWT->FUNCTION1 = 0x20B06;
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out what those register writes do exactly. Specifically, I don't get why `DWT->FUNCTION2` is set to 0. Any idea?

Comment: From arm architecture reference manual:

`If m is a comparator that defines a linked address comparison for use with a data value comparison, software must
program the DWT_FUNCTIONm.FUNCTION field to zero.`

Answer (score 1):

None of the software I know does it out of the box. When |I use the DWT usually I set it in my software. I have not found any way to program it via any variant of gdb (except manual setting the registers - but it is too annoying)